# Django makemessages not detecting translatable strings

Tags: python, django

In an app 'purchase', there is a file reports.py.  In this app, I'm generating some pdf-reports that sometimes I want to translate to the Czech language. Unfortunately the makemessages script doesn't detect the translatable strings.

Running the following shows that reports.py is being processed.  But no files are added.

```
.././manage.py makemessages -l cs_CZ -v 2
processing file reports.py in .
processing locale cs_CZ
```

This is a snippet from the reports.py file:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as trans

def purchase_order_report(purchase_order, language='en'):
    ...
    doc.add_text(trans('Items requested'), 'Heading2')
    ...
```

The Locale folder is setup like this:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "locale"),
)
```

---

Edit:
It seems that django makemessages is not correctly translating the import.

Running the following works (but may conflict when unpacking variables to _):

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

def purchase_order_report(purchase_order, language='en'):
    ...
    doc.add_text(_('Items requested'), 'Heading2')
    ...
```

Running the following works as well (but is not very handy if you want to mix and match ugettext and ugettext_lazy):

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext

def purchase_order_report(purchase_order, language='en'):
    ...
    doc.add_text(ugettext('Items requested'), 'Heading2')
    ...
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Apps should have a `locale` dir of their own. But it's not created if it does not exist. Create the directory within the app and then it should work.

Comment: I just created the locale dir inside of the 'purchase' app, and re-ran .././manage.py makemessages -l cs_CZ -v 2.   But the result is the same.

Comment: Is this python 3? And if not do you have `unicode_literals` imported from future?

Comment: It seems that the `import as` is not translated correctly.  I just edited the answer to add some more detail to my findings.  But in short, it seems you can only `import as _`.

Answer (score 0):

The `xgettext` GNU command accepts a `--keyword=KEYWORD` option in order to detect additionnal keywords.

I tried the following command in my shell and the result was as expected :

```
xgettext -o - --from-code=UTF-8 -L Python -d django -ktrans reports.py
```

Sadly, it seems that there is not any way to pass this option through the `makemessages` Django (2.1) command yet :'(
The keywords are hardcoded in the `django/core/management/commands/makemessage.py` file (around line 570).